# Whats wrong with the foreign-key constraint in this table?

Tags: join

table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed

the first create table my_seeking, works fine, when I try to run the create contactstoseeking I get the following err msg

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'db_ferguson.contactstoseeking'
>   (errno: 150)

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_seeking` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `seeking` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contactsTOseeking` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `seek` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `seek_UNIQUE` (`seek` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contactsTOseeking_my_seeking1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`my_seeking` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

A search of the web shows that err 150 is tied to my fk constraint.
Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table."

this code was generated BY MySQL, and this is my first attempt at foreign keys. I tried coding it manually and had issues so I thought that I would let workbench do it. WHAT EVER the problem is I cant see it or it is beyond my current skill set

Comment: whats-wrong-with-your-spacebar

Comment: would be helpful if you invested some time in formatting your question. I personally do not want to invest the time to extract your SQL from the bunch of characters above.

Comment: Database name is 'db_ferguson' or 'mydb'?

Comment: database name is "db_ferguson"

Comment: @JanDvorak, I did format it, when I pressed enter that is what it spit out, don't know what to say. everytime I post on this site and include code it does that

Comment: CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_seeking` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `seeking` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contactsTOseeking` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `seek` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `seek_UNIQUE` (`seek` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contactsTOseeking_my_seeking1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`my_seeking` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: @thst I honestly don't understand you statement, you don't see the window WITH nothing but code? Honestly what part of code do you think you need to EXTRACT????? JUST LIKE ABOVE                      CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_seeking` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `seeking` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contactsTOseeking` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `seek` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `seek_UNIQUE` (`seek` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contactsTOseeking_my.......

Comment: @bodhi926 now that it is formatted, I can read it. before it was all in one line like in your comment above. But your question is answered, so all seems to be fine now, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try removing the 'mydb' text in the reference? It indicates a table in 'mydb' database.

Comment: Your a life saver! Guess I couldn't see the forest for the trees, just stared at the code for too long and didn't see it, thanks!!!